# Inner Joined Subquery Vs. Outer Joined Subquery issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query that uses a subquery inner join, and I need to only fetch the first (matching) row from the subquery when it joins to the `EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM` table. I am facing an issue where when using `INNER JOIN` the query is not returning back the below `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID`, even though it exists in both the subquery and the outer (Main) query.

```
SELECT ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ORG.ORGANIZATION_CODE, PURCHASE_UOM_CODE.UNIT_OF_MEASURE
FROM EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM 

INNER JOIN      (SELECT DISTINCT UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, POL.ITEM_ID
                 FROM   INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_TL UOMT,
                        INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_B UOMB,
                        PO_HEADERS_ALL POH,
                        PO_LINES_ALL POL
                 WHERE  POH.PO_HEADER_ID = POL.PO_HEADER_ID
                        AND UOMB.UOM_CODE = POL.UOM_CODE
                        --AND POL.ITEM_ID = ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                        AND UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID = UOMB.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID
                        AND UOMT.LANGUAGE = USERENV('LANG')                            
                        AND  POH.TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'BLANKET'
                        AND ROWNUM = 1
                        --FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
) PURCHASE_UOM_CODE ON PURCHASE_UOM_CODE.ITEM_ID =ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
WHERE ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= '11223'
```

If I change the above query to use a `LEFT OUTER` join then it returns data I would expect, but I am concerned in some instances it may fetch more than I needed. I believe that the subquery is just fetching any random row in that table (not matching to main query) for another Item number and that is why the query does not return back data. Is there a way the subquery can reference the `ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID` column within the query itself, and not just on the Join condition? I tried joining POL.ITEM_ID = ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID within the subquery, however it does not recognize the outer column within it...

Or should I just use the LEFT OUTER JOIN in this case?

Comment: Where is ITEM_NUMBER in your query?

Comment: Selecting POL.Item_Id inside the subquery and then filtering it for a specific value is an overkill, don't you think? You are applying already that should be '11223'. All you need is the UNIT _OF_MEASURE from there - not sure if you really need all those old style inner joins there, maybe exists would be better and might even eliminate the distinct)

Answer (score 0):

You are picking a row at random in your subquery, and it happens not be the `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID` you want in your outer query block. You are correct that the problem is a conventional join on a subquery with a `ROWNUM` filter. You have to drive your predicate into the view, which you cannot do with that `ROWNUM` filter (or with the `DISTINCT`).

*"Is there a way the subquery can reference the ITM.ITEM_NUMBER column within the query itself, and not just on the Join condition?"*

Check out `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ORG.ORGANIZATION_CODE, PURCHASE_UOM_CODE.UNIT_OF_MEASURE
  FROM EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM 
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE
                 FROM   INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_TL UOMT,
                        INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_B UOMB,
                        PO_HEADERS_ALL POH,
                        PO_LINES_ALL POL
                 WHERE  POH.PO_HEADER_ID = POL.PO_HEADER_ID
                        AND UOMB.UOM_CODE = POL.UOM_CODE
                        --AND POL.ITEM_ID = ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                        AND UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID = UOMB.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID
                        AND UOMT.LANGUAGE = USERENV('LANG')                            
                        AND  POH.TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'BLANKET'
                        AND POL.ITEM_ID =ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID -- DRIVING PREDICATE HERE
                        AND ROWNUM = 1
            ) PURCHASE_UOM_CODE
 WHERE ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= '11223'
```

Since you only want one column you could simply put the subquery in your `SELECT` clause. But once you need more than one column, this is a powerful technique.

Comment: I thought about just putting the subquery back in the SELECT area, however I have another column (not shown above) that is using conditional Case statement that references the subquery column above...

Comment: Can the ROWNUM function be referenced on the Join clause, instead of inside the subquery? This would also resolve the issue I think...

Comment: You can put ROWNUM inside the block, if you use CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY to drive the predicate into it. You can put it outside the block also, as long as you only want 1 row from the whole query. I actually would discourage the use of ROWNUM though. It's better to use aggregation (e.g. MAX) or a windowing function (e.g. ROW_NUMBER) to decide how to deal with multiple values when you want only one.

Comment: just curious how does the inner query (for lack of a better word) "join" to the outer query with this CROSS APPLY?

Comment: AND POL.ITEM_ID =ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID -- DRIVING PREDICATE HERE   .. you might have to refresh the screen to see the comment I added later to make it stand out.

Comment: You can add it back. I think I misread it as inventory_item_id which would have been redundant.

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to run this - ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Comment: Double check syntax, make sure you are using CROSS APPLY and do not have an ON clause and aren't using (+) for the driving predicate inside the subquery. Also ensure your database is 12c or higher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253195/discussion-between-nick-and-paul-w).

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is pointless in the inner sub-query as you are also filtering where `ROWNUM = 1` so that one row will always be distinct.

It looks like you can move the sub-query to the outer query and then filter using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
       ORGANIZATION_CODE,
       UNIT_OF_MEASURE
FROM   (
  SELECT ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
         ORG.ORGANIZATION_CODE,
         UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
           ORDER BY ROWNUM -- or something more appropriate
         ) AS rn
  FROM   EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM 
         INNER JOIN PO_LINES_ALL POL
         ON POL.ITEM_ID =ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
         INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL POH
         ON POH.PO_HEADER_ID = POL.PO_HEADER_ID
         INNER JOIN INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_B UOMB
         ON UOMB.UOM_CODE = POL.UOM_CODE
         INNER JOIN INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_TL UOMT
         ON UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID = UOMB.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID
  WHERE  UOMT.LANGUAGE = USERENV('LANG')                            
  AND    POH.TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'BLANKET'
  AND    ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= '11223'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

However, since you have the filter `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= '11223'` then there will only ever be one partition used in the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function so you could simplify it to:

```sql
SELECT ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
       ORG.ORGANIZATION_CODE,
       UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE
FROM   EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM 
       INNER JOIN PO_LINES_ALL POL
       ON POL.ITEM_ID =ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
       INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL POH
       ON POH.PO_HEADER_ID = POL.PO_HEADER_ID
       INNER JOIN INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_B UOMB
       ON UOMB.UOM_CODE = POL.UOM_CODE
       INNER JOIN INV_UNITS_OF_MEASURE_TL UOMT
       ON UOMT.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID = UOMB.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID
WHERE  UOMT.LANGUAGE = USERENV('LANG')                            
AND    POH.TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'BLANKET'
AND    ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= '11223'
AND    ROWNUM = 1;
```